# How do I get the browser's current url in Linux?

Tags: linux, browser, dde

In Windows it is easy to get the current url from most browsers using simple DDE commands. Likewise with DDE you can tell the browser to go to another location.

How do I do a similar task in Linux? I need to retrieve the url the browser is pointing to for a tool I am making.

I know of no DDE equivalents in Linux but usually the command line can do magick tricks...

Preferred browser: Firefox or Chrome in that order.

Comment: Side note, as far as I know the closest Linux equivalent of DDE (as far as allowing external process control) would be [D-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus). Google results seem to indicate that both FF and Chromium support D-bus, but I don't know much about it. It may or may not be the ideal way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: a little experiment shows that neither FF nor Cr seem to support D-bus.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky; I have made this free browser tool for Windows which has been very popular: http://www.kreacom.dk/optool/ . It allows to see a given webpage in many different browsers using a global shortcut. Nice for developers! It has not been actively developed for a couple of years because I am on Linux now and I wish too make a Linux version as well. For this, I need to be able to control the browsers.